# Module dependency on resource causes Terraform destroy error

Tags: terraform

I have the following in `main.tf`.

```
resource "random_string" "user" {
    length = 12
    special = false
}

module "my_mod" {
    source = "../../my_mod"
    user = "${random_string.user.result}"
}
```

On `terraform destroy`this produces the following error:

```
Resource 'random_string.user' does not have attribute 'result' for variable 'random_string.user.result'.
```

I'm presuming this is because TF has destroyed the random string resource before the custom module?  Is there a way to tell it to destroy the module first and then the resource?

Comment: Can you show the destroy output after a fresh apply?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR ah ok, ran an apply and destroy and it's all fine this time.  Is that what your were getting at?

Comment: More that it was hard to see what was wrong from what you described. Terraform can already see that the module has a dependency on the random string and so equally it knows it has to destroy what's in the module before destroying the random string. It's hard to tell what might have been wrong at this point but good to know you've resolved your issue.